# get info from dynamic (javascript) webpage in script

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-deployment

I need to get a div from webpage, witch use ajax to generate it. 
something like :
Get_page->run_JScript_for_moment->take_snapshot->parse_html_for_div->save_to_sql 
I try to use CasperJS and I can't get snapshot as html (but as screenshot I can)

```
this.capture('gin.png'); // Return site after run JS
this.echo(this.getHTML()); // Return code before run JS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked with PhantomJS -- not Casper -- but I believe Casper is built on top of Phantom.  I do know that generating the png takes longer than just retrieving the html, so maybe just try a setTimeout to wait a few hundred milliseconds before running the getHTML method.

```
setTimeout(this.echo, 250, this.getHTML())
```

Comment: thanks... it works good but i still cant get Facebook chat info